# Keeping track of Deleted Entries between mobile Local Database and optional Cloud Database

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Mobile App, where the main feature has the user do a lot of CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) tasks within it.

The main storage of data for the App is a local sqlite database, but the user has the option to register an account and use Cloud database to backup their data.

This App needs to be able to work both offline and online. And the user should be able to use multiple devices containing the same data.

Currently in all of my sql tables I have 3 extra columns that keep track of which entries in the database is synced: createdAt(datetime), updatedAt(datetime) and synced(boolean).
With this I am able to keep track of which entries are the most recent, and update either the local or the cloud database accordingly.

I'm using Cloud Firestore as the Cloud, and using its' Offline capabilities is not a viable option in my case.

**My Question is; Which solution would be the best when keeping track of deleted entries until the App is able to sync with the cloud?**

One idea for a solution for this is to have an table that contains all the ID's of deleted entries together with which table it belongs, and then when the App is able to sync; remove these entries on both the local database(on all devices) and the cloud database.
The problem I have with this solution is that, this 'deletion' table quickly will become huge, and removing entries from this table would be a problem, because of the need of all the user's devices to be up-to-date before deletion and in a scenario where the user has abandoned one of his devices, this would mean that the device would never sync, resulting in the entries not being remove from the 'deletion' table.

**What would your suggestion be for a robust way of tracking deleted entries?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a solution that satisfies both these objectives:

1. Don't keep deleted items in the database forever
2. Make sure deletions are synchronized between all devices forever

So you will have to decide which one to give up on.  Your idea satisfies 2 but not 1.  A solution that would satisfy 1 but not 2 is to delete the deletion records after a period of time, maybe six months.  A variation on that would be when a record is deleted, rather than actually deleting it just mark it as deleted (as well as the date when it was deleted), and if applicable remove any large pieces of data from the record.  After whatever grace period you decide, the record can be actually deleted.  The down side is that if a mothballed device is brought back out, it could restore previously deleted records.